# jQuery file upload validation are not working

Tags: jquery

code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( "#myform" ).validate({
        rules: {
            user_image: {
                required: true,
                extension: "jpeg|jpg|png"
            },
            user_resume:{
                required:true,
                extension: "docx|doc"
            }
        }
    });
</script>
<form method="post" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='file' name='user_image' id='user_image'>
    <input type='file' name='user_resume' id='user_resume'>
</form>
```

In this code I have create a simple form where I have two input field type is file. In first input field I want to validate user_image with jpeg|jpg|png extension similarly in case of user_resume input field I want to validate with docx|doc extension file but this is not working yet. I do't know why. So, How can I do this ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: where is your `#myform` ?!!

Comment: You probably also need to wrap your logic in a document.handler

Comment: Review my code @ZakariaAcharki

Comment: Seems that it work just fine, check https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/563/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. It works fine.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $("#user_image").change(function () {

        var val = $(this).val();

        switch (val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()) {
            case 'gif': case 'jpg': case 'png':
                alert("an image");
                break;
            default:
                $(this).val('');
                // error message here
                alert("not an image");
                
                break;
        }
    });
    $("#user_resume").change(function () {

        var val = $(this).val();

        switch (val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()) {
            case 'doc': case 'docx':
                alert("A Reume");
                break;
            default:
                $(this).val('');
                // error message here
                alert("not A Reume");
              
                break;
        }
    });
   
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='file' name='user_image' id='user_image'>
    <input type='file' name='user_resume' id='user_resume'>
```